# Problema que tengo con herencia en Java

Tags: java, poo, herencia

```
public class GestionRepartoLocal {  
    // CÓDIGO DE APOYO
    private ArrayList<Moto> motosDisponibles;
    private ArrayList<Furgoneta> furgonetasDisponibles;

    private ArrayList<Pedido> pedidosEsperandoMoto;
    private ArrayList<Pedido> pedidosEsperandoFurgoneta;

    //Con sus respectivos setter y getter para las listas

    public void add(Transporte transporte){
        //TO-DO
    }
    public void notificarEntregaPedido(Pedido pedido) { 
        //TO-DO
        motosDisponibles.add(motosDisponibles.size(), pedido.getTransporte());

    }
}
```

No encuentro la forma de averiguar si el objeto de tipo transporte (que se obtiene de "pedido") es un objeto de clase Moto o Furgoneta.  Estas dos últimas son clases hijas de la clase transporte.

```
public class Transporte {

    private String codigo;
    private Mapa mapa;

    public Transporte(String codTransporte, Mapa map) {
        this.codigo = codTransporte;
        this.mapa = map;

    }

    public double coste(String posDestino){
        double costeTransporte = mapa.distancia(codigo, posDestino);
        return costeTransporte;
    }

    public double coste(String cod1, String cod2) {
        double costeTransporte = mapa.distancia(cod1, cod2);
        return costeTransporte;
    }

    public String getCodigo(){
        return codigo;
    }

    public Mapa getMapa() {
        return mapa;
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano a quien responda. Soy nueva escribiendo en el foro, pero no por ello, no conociese la página. En anteriores ocasiones para resolver dudas y que fueron preguntadas/contestadas por otros usuarios que me sirvieron de mucho.

Comment: Podrias agregar una propiedad `Tipo` a la clase Transporte.

Comment: Podrías usar instanceOf me parece

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que con el instanceof ya me da una idea de como hacerlo, si sale bien os lo comento. Gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java tiene la palabra reservada `instanceof`. Si tienes algo como

```
class Transporte {...}

class Motocicleta extends Transporte {...}
```

Entonces puedes hacer algo como

```
if (miObjeto instanceof Motocicleta) {
    Motocicleta m = (Motocicleta)miObjeto;
    ... 
}
```

Este operador no sólo es `true` con la clase de la que has usado el constructor, también es verdad con cualquier clase padre:

```
Transporte m= new Motocicleta();
boolean b= (m instanceof Transporte) && (m instanceof Motocicleta); //true
```